# Assassins Creed 2 tcp and udp ports

Tags: tcp, udp, port, firewall

I need to know which are the TCP and UDP ports of assassins creed 2 beacause IT is blocking all connections, but my team needs to run some test with the game and some others, so IT asked to give them the ports so they can open the connection. 
I did a research and found other games ports except AC2.

It seems that Ubisoft have this information well hidden, maybe because of the DRM and cracks? I have the original game and only want to open the firewall.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They may not be published but they are certainly not well hidden. Fire up something like Wireshark and see what traffic AC2 is generating. Filter to view only outbound traffic and as long as you don't have many other services running AC2 packets should be easy to identify. Wireshark will show you a breakdown of the packets including the port numbers.

Comment: The problem here is that IT takes a long time to open the firewall and if I use wireshark at the start, I will only see some ports (login) and not the in-game used ports, and I want to know all the used ports prior to open a ticket.

Comment: @Victor:  Fire up Wireshark at home, where your ports are all open.  Do this multiple times, in case AC2 uses a range of ports.

Comment: Or open a VM without any firewalls NAT or bridged